# Where is the Strong Markov property(SM) being used in the proof that augmented filtration of a Strong Markov process is right continuous?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-process, stochastic-analysis, filtrations

I was self-reading Section 2.7 of Karatzas and Shreve's Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus and Proposition 7.7 claims that the Strong Markov processes augmented filtration is right continuous. In the proof(screenshots below), according to me only the Markov property is being used since we consider only a deterministic optional time $s$ in the proof.

I understand most of the details in the proof but it seems I don't really see where exactly is the strong Markov property is being used?
[image]

I am at a total loss and I would really appreciate if someone could help me here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that the strong Markov property is not used in its full generality; somehow, it's an artifact of the definition of the (strong) Markov property by Karatzas & Shreve. They say that $(X_t,\mathcal{F}_t)_t$ is Markov if

$$\mathbb{E}(f(X_{s+t}) \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = \mathbb{E}(f(X_{s+t}) \mid X_s) \tag{1}$$

and strong Markov if

$$\mathbb{E}(f(X_{S+t}) \mid \mathcal{F}_{S+}) = \mathbb{E}(f(X_{S+t}) \mid X_S) \tag{2}$$

for any optional time $S$. Clearly, $(2)$ implies

$$\mathbb{E}(f(X_{s+t}) \mid \mathcal{F}_{s+}) = \mathbb{E}(f(X_{s+t}) \mid X_s) \tag{3}$$

Note that $(3)$ differs from $(1)$ since we are conditioning on $\mathcal{F}_s$ and $\mathcal{F}_{s+}$, respectively. It follows easily from the tower property that $(3)$ implies $(1)$ but the converse is not immediate. Karatzes-Shreve need $(3)$ for the proof of the right-continuity of the filtration, and therefore they are refering to the strong Markov property.

The proof by Karatzas-Shreve actually shows the following statement (which can be, for instance, also found in the book by Blumenthal & Getoor)

> If $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ satisfies the Markov property with respect to $(\mathcal{F}_{t+})_{t \geq 0}$, then the augmented natural filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is right-continuous and $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Markov process with respect to $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful explanation. So if we assume strong Markov , and use the full power of the definition(for any optional time), can we say more about the filtration(for example left continuity)?

Comment: and doesnt the proof in KS(proposition show ) that the augmented filtration(\mathcal{F}_t^{\mu}) is right continuous and not the natural filtration?

Comment: @user3503589 1) Not as far as I know. The left-continuity of the filtration is actually closely connected to the regularity of the sample paths (for instance if $(X_t)_t$ has continuous sample paths, then the filtration is left-continuous). 2) Ah, right, I forgot to add "augmented"... should be fine now.

Comment: do you the exact reference for the proof in Blumenthal & Getoor?

Comment: I am asking this because in proposition 8.12 in the book on page 42, they claim that if a process is Markov w.r.t to $\mathcal{F}_{t+}$, then the natural(\textbf{not the natural augmented filtration}) is right continuous

Comment: @user3503589 I don't have the book here right now; I'll check it out tomorrow. Why does it worry you that the natural (and not the augmented natural filtration) might be right-continuous? Unless I miss something obvious, it should be rather straight-forward to show tat right-continuity of the filtration implies right-continuity of the augmented filtration (... which would mean that Blumenthal+Getoor show, in particular, the result which I stated in my answer).

Comment: I am sorry . I checked what you said and you are right . I thought it wasn’t straight forward to show this but it’s very straight forward to show it